# Kinesis Firehose during a Redshift pause?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm using Firehose to put a data stream into Redshift via S3. The Redshift cost is eye watering for the small amount of data I have at the moment, so I'm looking to pause Redshift for up to 23 hours a day.

Redshift has the ability to schedule periodic pause and resume, but the Firehose retry policy means once a Redshift retry fails, it simply records an error manifest in S3 and continues as usual, but only processing new data.

Is there any way to tell Firehose to re-try the records that failed to load?

Or alternatively, a way to tell Firehose to avoid running the copy command when Redshift is paused so that the data can be safely loaded when Redshift is running?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Seems as a redshift is an overkill for your use case. Have you considered other solutions, regaular RDS database for example?

Comment: You could consider making Firehose [sink to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-s3) instead, and use an [external table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) in Redshift. That way there would be no need for a COPY, and the data would be automatically 'loaded' only once you resume your Redshift cluster and query the external table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Marcin and Schepo. I think I'll take advice from both of you, but instead of using an external Redshift table, I'll just load the Firehose data to S3 and then load directly from S3 into Quicksight - no need for Redshift till I have more data. Thanks again.